# worksheetfunction equivalent in Word vba

Tags: vba, function, date, ms-word

I'm having problems with a word document system I'm creating.

Each Word document has a custom document property called `MtgDate` that needs to be set on `document_open`. There are quite a few different documents and all will require slightly different formulas for these.
In Excel, the formula for the currently relevant date for the one I'm currently working on would be

```
=WORKDAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(), 0), -2)
```

that is, the third-to-last day of the current month. If I wanted to calculate this in Excel VBA I'd replace `TODAY()` with `Date` and put `WorksheetFunction.` at the start of the other functions. However this isn't an option in Word VBA - can anyone tell me of a viable alternative to the `EOMONTH` and `WORKDAY` functions please? Or an alternative to `Worksheetfunction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the next function, please:

```
Private Function EOMonth(dInput As Date) As Date
   EOMonth = DateSerial(Year(dInput), Month(dInput) + 1, 0)
End Function
```

Next function will deal only with working days (adding or subtracting):

```
Function WorkDayWord(start_date As Date, days As Long) As Date
 Dim count_days As Long, boolPos As Boolean

 If days >= 0 Then
    boolPos = True: days = days - 1
 Else
    days = days + 1
 End If
 count_days = 1

 Do Until IIf(boolPos, days < 1, days > 1) And _
          Weekday(DateAdd("d", count_days, start_date)) <> 1 And _
              Weekday(DateAdd("d", count_days, start_date)) <> 7

    If Weekday(DateAdd("d", count_days, start_date)) = 1 Or _
            Weekday(DateAdd("d", count_days, start_date)) = 7 Then
        days = days
        count_days = count_days + IIf(boolPos, 1, -1)
    Else
        days = IIf(boolPos, days - 1, days + 1)
        count_days = count_days + IIf(boolPos, 1, -1)
    End If
 Loop
 WorkDayWord = DateAdd("d", count_days, start_date)
End Function
```

It must be adapted (if it does not return as you need) according to first day of the month setting...

It can be used in this way, in order to do what the invoked Excel function does:

```
Sub ThirdToLastEndOFMonth()
   Debug.Print WorkDayWord(EOMonth("10.06.2020"), -2)'a month where the difference between weekdays and workdays can be observed...
   Debug.Print WorkDayWord(EOMonth(Date), -2)
End Sub
```

Comment: What about when `dInput` is in December? Wouldn't that cause an error when `Month(dInput)+1` = 13?

Comment: @Spencer Barnes: Did you test it? Excel know hows how to deal with such a situation. For instance `DateSerial(2020, 13, 1)` will return first of January... You can easily simulate what you imagine being something wrong: `Debug.Print EOMonth("12/15/2020") - 3`. What does it return?

Comment: Nope, you're right. Well done on an elegant solution!!

Comment: @Spencer Barnes: Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody places a piece of code solving our problem, vote the code up and most important, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar, will know that the solution works... :)

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru, but I can't completely accept your answer as it didn't provide a mimic for the 'WORKDAY' part too. You deserved the vote up I gave though.

Comment: @Spencer Barnes: OK. I missed that part... Do you also want counting the holidays as not workdays?  This part looks obviously easier, if not holidays involved...

Comment: Personally I've found a workaround myself now (see my own answer below), and in this specific application I don't need holidays, but if you have the expertise / time or can see a better method than I used, by all means go ahead.

Comment: @Spencer Barnes: OK. Good for you! I adapted the above code to directly return what you want, without any 'Workday` function need...

Comment: not quite, I need the Workday function so it skips weekends. Very close though.

Comment: @Spencer Barnes: Ups... Not very complicated to prepare a function able to deal with workdays, I think...

Comment: @Spencer Barnes: `DateAdd("w", Days, Date)` works with weekdays **not with workdays**...

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of that, as per my answer and earlier comments.

Comment: @Spencer Barnes: Should I understand that you supplied a solution for Workdays and I missed it? I only saw "the Excel Function WORKDAY(Date, Days) almost equals the VBA Function DateAdd("w", Days, Date) - the difference of course being that Excel WORKDAY allows for holidays, which in this instance I don't need". In my opinion this is not true. I can admit that English is not my best point and I am asking myself if my (language) understanding was wrong...

Comment: Not quite - I never figured a solution for the holidays part of WORKDAY function, but I didn't need to use that part in my task, so my makeshift solution (effectively weekdays) was close enough for me. So yes your understanding was right, it wasn't an exact solution for WORKDAYS.

Comment: @Spencer Barnes:  But I've just offered a solution for Workdays. Did you test it?

Answer (score 1):

You sometimes have to create your own functions to achieve what you want. For example you can mimic the `EOMONTH` worksheet function like this

```
Function EOMonth(lStartDate As Long, lMonths As Long) As Long
  EOMonth = DateSerial(Year(lStartDate), Month(lStartDate) + lMonths + 1, 1) - 1
End Function
```

This can be a lot of fun and you will get a great sense of achievenment :)

There's also another option: You can access excel's worksheet functions from an excel application object.

```
Sub UseExcelWorksheetFunctions()
  Dim xlApp As Object, wf As Object
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set wf = xlApp.WorksheetFunction
  MsgBox Format(wf.EoMonth(Date, 0), "dd/mm/yyyy")
  ' Cleanup code here
End Sub
```

For me, this approach only makes sense if I am creating an excel application in my project anyway, otherwise I would be averse to using this approach. But the choice is yours.

Comment: Hi, would you mind explaining what you meant by 'cleanup code' please? Not because I'll be using it in this specific application, but I've always had issues with VBA when calling one application from another, and think this might be something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured an answer myself but posting it here cos it wasn't at all clear online. Big thanks to @SuperSymmetry and @FaneDuru for your answers too though, they definitely helped me with the thinking-through!

The secret lies in the vba `DateAdd` Function, in which it mysteriously asks for `Interval as String, Number as Double, Date`. To add Weekdays (technically different to the Excel `WORKDAY` because it doesn't allow for any holidays), you just need to put "W" or "w" as the Interval, with `Number` being how many of the specified interval you want to add (or remove if it's negative). For a complete list of intervals go [here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/functions/dateadd-function.htm) or check the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function).

The `EOMonth` mimic can be done using the same principle. (EDIT: However the other ways of doing this as shown in the answers I got work as well if not better). If you're doing this, you use the Interval "m" to add a Month to `DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(date), 1)` (to get the start of next month) then minus 1 day.

I'm putting this out here purely because nowhere on the internet did I find a clear simple explanation that says that **the Excel Function `WORKDAY(Date, Days)` almost equals the VBA Function `DateAdd("w", Days, Date)`** - the difference of course being that Excel WORKDAY allows for holidays, which in this instance I don't need.

Anyway there it is, and I hope it helps someone.